# publish reviews of one site to our facebook page using facebook sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I need to publish the reviews of our company website automatically(or manually) to our company's facebbok page.. Is that possible using facebook php sdk?

Comment: If you mean the actual page review/ratings feature - no, those can not be created via API. If you just want to create normal posts - yes, that is possible, but in that case your question is way too broad, you need to go and do your own proper research on that.

Comment: reviews are made by facebook users, how would that ever work?

Comment: @CBroe then i have to send the review pages as link. Am i right?

Comment: @luschn my doubt was is that possible to pull the reviews from our website and publish on our facebook page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to post to the ratings API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

You would need a Facebook User Access Token anyway, i assume the reviews on the website are not bound to any Facebook User.